# How to replace some text in PHP without the text in between effecting the process

Tags: php, regex

I want to ask is there any way to replace text in PHP without the text in between effecting the replacing process using `preg_replace`?
For example, I want to replace `Hello Adel, How are you?` with `Bye Adel, See you later!`, with the fact that Adel can be any other name or full name (for example: `Sia`, `Tyler`, `smoked salmon`)

Like this (`OriginalText ==> ModifiedText`):

`Hello Someone That I don't know, how are you? ==> Bye Someone That I don't know, see you later!
Hello User, how are you? ==> Bye User, see you later!`


like if `Hello` and `some combination of words` then `,how are you?` will be replaced with `Bye` and `some combination of words` then `, see you later!` using `preg_replace`
and if it's not possible to do using `preg_replace`, tell me how can I do it in other ways

Comment: what do you mean @user3783243 ?

Comment: yeah, this isn't what I want

Comment: So `Hello ANYTHING, How are you?` and replace with `Bye ANYTHING, See you later!`? If so maybe https://3v4l.org/hAskL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a capture group `()` to get the variable text from the middle of the pattern, and refer to it in the replacement using a backreference (`$1`).

```
$after = preg_replace(
    '/Hello (.+), How are you\?/',
    'Bye $1, See you later!',
    $before
);
```